# How to autocomplete the env variable in nextjs13,typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

For our current `env` usage, we created a `.env.local` file and set it up like this

```
site_url=https://qweqwewqeq.com
```

However, when I use it, it doesn't autocomplete after env.process. how can I make it autocomplete?
[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-process-env-type#define-types-for-processenv-in-typescript